# Как посчитать количество в определенный день?

Tags: php, sql

Как с помошью запроса узнать сколько записей было сделанно в определенный день.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Должен получить результат

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: что значит id должно быть уникально? для конкретного id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

если столбец `time` у вас строка, то

```
 select count(distinct id), `time`
 from t
 group by time
```

если же это вдруг `datetime`, то используйте функцию `date()` в выборке и группирвоке

Comment: И в итоге мы получим https://prnt.sc/pwyxek

Comment: А должно показать, то что я приложыл на втором скриншоте

Comment: @АндрейИсаев прочитайте последнее слово моего ответа еще раз.

Comment: Дико извеняюсь, виноват.